# What is the name of the apache process owner?

Tags: apache-2.4, lamp

After running

```
$ps aux | grep httpd
```

the terminal output is

```
root     26923  0.0  0.0  14428  1044 pts/0    S+   17:43   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

I'm trying to change the owner of a path on a remote LAMP server.

According to this question; move_uploaded_file gives "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error the next step after running

```
$ps aux | grep httpd
```

Is to "Change the owner of images and tmp_file_upload to be become nobody or whatever the owner you found in step 1."

```
$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/images/

$sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/mysite/tmp_file_upload/
```

What should my terminal input for the chown command be based off of my terminal output when running ps aux | grep httpd?

The author of the answer also stated The first column will be the owner typically it will be nobody. What should be used instead of `nobody` here, or will `nobody` work?

Comment: On Debian based systems (what your path of /var/www indicates) the Apache binary is called `apache2`, not `httpd`.

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this php > error.log message? `[24-Jul-2020 22:02:24 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(upload/52.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/api.php on line 81
[24-Jul-2020 22:02:24 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php1LzNXL' to 'upload/52.jpg' in /var/www/html/api.php on line 81` ?

Comment: I can ask that in another quest. I'll gladly accept your answer in answer format! tY!